# An infinite cardinal number into a power of a finite cardinal number

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

In "Naive Set Theory" Halmos gives an exercise:

> Prove that if $a, b$ are cardinal numbers, $a$ is infinite, $b$ is finite, then $a^b = a$

I struggle to use the known properties of cardinal numbers as well as induction on $b$ (if it is applicable here at all) or thinking about it in terms of sets of functions.

It is written in the Wikipedia that this property requires the Axiom of Choice, and in the book it is assumed.

Comment: It is sufficient to show that $a\times a=a$, and then you can proceed by induction. So the key is proving that if $a$ is infinite, then (with AC) $a\times a$ is bijectable with $a$.

Comment: "then (with AC) a×a is bijectable with a" That's a slightly tall order!"  (Nitpick:  $a$ is the cardinal number not the set.  I think you mean if $|A|=a$ then $a^2=|A\times A|$)

Comment: @fleablood: cardinals are sets. It is perfectly sensible to say “$a\times a$ is bijectable with $a$”. No, I do not mean what you seem to think I mean, because that would not do anything for the problem at hand. You would still need to show that $a=a^2$, i.e., that $A$ is bijectable with $A\times A$; i.e., that $a$ is bijectable with $a\times a$... which is exactly what I said to being with.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you, the proof that $a \cdot a = a$ was given in the book, it used Zorn's Lemma (thus the AC), and I understood it. Then I'd continue following your advice like: let $\text{card}~A = a$, $\text{card}~B = b$, where $b \sim \omega$. Proof by induction on $b$, let $b = 1$, then it's obvious, let the statement hold for $b = k$ then $a^{k+1} = a^k \cdot a = a \cdot a = a$, so it holds for $b = k + 1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Halmos tells that there are two equivalent definitions of exponentiation for cardinal numbers, via repeated multiplication or $a ^ b = \text{card}~ A^B$. He uses the latter to show all the properties, that's why I hesitated to use the definition of exponentiation as a repeated multiplication.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin it is actually the last exercise from the penultimate chapter of the book... so I can't wait to start studying some other textbook about the Set Theory (with all the respect to Halmos book, I'd like to find a more substantial one, because the Halmos book seems a bit introductory despite all the struggles that it brought to me as a first introduction into Set Theory)

Comment: @AndreySurovtsev: You don't need the definition as "repeated multiplication". You just need to show that $A^{B+1}$ is bijectable with $(A^B)\times A$, which is easy: any function from $B\cup\{B\}$ to $A$ corresponds to a function from $B$ to $A$ plus an element of $A$, i.e., an element of $A^B\times A$; and vice-versa. More generally, if $B$ and $C$ are disjoint, then $A^{B\cup C}$ is bijectable with $(A^B)\times(A^C)$. This gives you the formula for cardinals $a^{b+c} = a^b\cdot a^c$.